# Always got error while checking if file exist or not using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I always got return false or file not found while try to checking file using Nodejs. Here's my code in file updatePrice.js

```
var filepath = './../logs/update-price.log';
fs.access(filepath, fs.F_OK, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        return res.send("Exist");
    } else {
        return res.send("None");
    }
});
```

And here's my sample project folder structure

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fs.stat or fs.statSync

```
function fileExists(path) {
  try {
    fs.statSync(path)
  } catch(err) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For under Node.js v0.12.x

```
var path = require('path');

path.exists('./../logs/update-price.log', function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
        // Exists
    } else {
        // Doesn't exist
    }
});
```

For Node.js v0.12.x

```
fs.stat('foo.txt', function(err, stat) {
    if(err == null) {
        // Exists
    } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        // Doesn't exist
    } else {
        // Insufficient permissions
    }
});
```